# how to display a user name in url

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how I can display the name of user in the URL?

If the name is passed in the URL:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
echo "Welcome back" .$username ;
```

i want to display like
www.example.com/username when he login

How can I display the name after a user logged in?

Comment: Why is this not secure? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Did you heared about SESSION?

Comment: @septi Because if someone is called `<script>...</script>` then your users will be victims of cross site scripting.

Answer (score 7):

Saving the username in a `$_SESSION` variable should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

What you show is perfectly secure as long as you sanitize the data:

```
$username = $_GET['username']; 
echo "Welcome back" .htmlspecialchars($username);
```

However, this can still be changed by the user of course. Depending on your use case, storing the user name in a session as mentioned by @Mark may be preferable.

Comment: ok dear .but i want to dislpay in url like www.example.com/username

Comment: @ritu it's the same thing. I don't really understand what your question is then, you should edit the text to clarify

Comment: i can change the text but this will not done from this i can't do this

Comment: simple i want to display the user name in the url when he logged in

Comment: @ritu But *why*? That's kinda pointless. Why not just store the username in a [session variable](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) when they login like: `$_SESSION['username'] = $username_variable;` and `$username_variable` would be the username that the user logged in with. Displaying it in directory format (example.com/username) would be a lot more work that isn't really needed. Just make a page and then fill in the user (that is logged in) details from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php - using either of these functions should help guard against XSS, etc.

Comment: `htmlentities()` is not harmful, but stinks for various reasons (mainly because it unnecessarily turns non-ASCII characters into their entities). `htmspecialchars()` is the way to go.